# Flash AS security question

Tags: flash, actionscript

I don't know Flash AS at all, used to experiment when I was 15, but not anymore. Anyway, I wanted to know if there is a way to make swf files check which domain they're being loaded from and the react accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "which domain they're being loaded from" do you mean:

1. The SWF itself?
2. The page that contains the SWF?

If #1, you can get the value easily from the `root.loaderInfo.url` property of any display object.

#2 is trickier. If `allowscriptaccess` is set to `true` in the embed code, you can use Javascript with an ExternalInterface call. It's on the `document.location.host` or `document.location.hostname`.

If you don't have access to Javascript (like if your SWF is in a Facebook post), you'll need to do a little setup, and the solution will be dependent on the user's browser behaving. Here's one way to do it:

Set up a server-side script that your SWF can ping. This script should look for the http "referer" header, and send that back when pinged. Then have your SWF send a URLRequest to this script. The data will be the embedding site.

In PHP, the script would just be `echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];`. It's similarly simple in most other languages.

Here's another way to do it:
[How do I get the domain of the page that's loading my swf when I don't have script access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994519/how-do-i-get-the-domain-of-the-page-thats-loading-my-swf-when-i-dont-have-scrip)

If you just want to protect your SWF from being embedded in others' pages, that's easier. Just check for `ExternalInterface.available`. If it's false, disable the SWF. If it's true, check the domain using the above (#1) method and disable the SWF if the domain is wrong.