# Get domain of server where swf is being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash

I have SWF hosted on a domain lets say www.aaa.com. I am embedding that swf in an html page which is on www.bbb.com. Now, within the SWF, how can I get the domain where SWF is being embedded i.e. in my example www.bbb.com?

I can do it via javascript and then pass the domain name to as3, but I want to do it from within the SWF due to certain requirements. Also, i don't want to load my SWF in another SWF which is on www.bbb.com.

Any answers...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the domain of the page that's loading my swf when I don't have script access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994519/how-do-i-get-the-domain-of-the-page-thats-loading-my-swf-when-i-dont-have-scri)

Comment: Ok, by reading that question, turns out there is no straightforward way of doing this. Thanks Jan for pointing out that question.

Answer (score 1):

you say you are embedding the flash on the bbb domain, so i guess you have access to the bbb's server page generator.

in that case i would just include the domain name in the flashVars, for example: `topdomain=<?php echo(urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])); ?>`

and then access the topdomain variable inside the swf. in case it's undefined, assume that it's embedded from somewhere else

Comment: Yes, I know about that, but I was looking for a way to find the domain name from inside swf, not writing anything in javascript or by passing variables. @Jan Hančič pointed out a similar question to mine which suggests that there is no way in AS3 we can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in any sprite:

```
//this will work in any pure AS3 class
var sp:Sprite = new Sprite;
trace(sp.loaderInfo.url);
```

If you are using Flex, then do this after the child is added to the stage/display list.

To get the domain, you can use regular expression to parse the url, or just look for the string between "http://" and "/".